# What kind of bug hangs Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to debug a simple cross-platform commandline program (a C parser, itself written in C) and running into something strange.

On Windows, when I run it on a small dataset (the source code of glib) it completes successfully, and when I run it on a large dataset (the source code of the Linux kernel) it exits with an out of memory error. I'm not sure whether the latter is a bug in my code or just a consequence of not just having optimized the memory consumption yet, so I've been trying to run it on Linux so I can get some feedback from valgrind.

On Linux (Ubuntu 11.04 x64 in VirtualBox), when I run my program on a small dataset it completes successfully, and when I run it on a large dataset Linux locks up hard enough I have to reset the entire virtual box (mouse pointer still moves but other than that it's completely unresponsive; Windows task manager says the virtual box is using one hundred percent of a CPU core but not allocating memory).

I wouldn't have expected a bug in my code to crash Linux unless I was writing something like a device driver, and when I try simple test cases that allocate too much memory, go into an infinite loop or both, Linux can handle them just fine. What kind of bug should I be looking for, or what am I missing?

Comment: Umm... Where's the code? And have you tried to step through with a debugger?

Comment: There are tons of "bugs" that can do this. Most common for me is Linux switching to swap space when you run out of RAM. On Windows you get an error, but on Linux, you start writing RAM to disk to create more space. Trouble is, disk I/O speeds are much, much slower than RAM I/O speeds.

Comment: NickLH, http://ayane.co and when I try running it under gdb I get the same result. It runs for a little while before hanging, so can't single step to the error.

Comment: Blender, oddly enough I get the reverse - on Windows when I run out of RAM, the machine can lock up for minutes while it goes into swap, but Linux just kills the rogue process within a very few seconds.

Comment: @rwallace In the described scenario Linux does not run native but virtualized. This may make a difference in such a scenario.

Comment: AH, given that, any idea what kind of bug I should be looking for that might cause virtualized Linux to hang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely an infinite loop (easily done in a parser), which could easily take up 100% cpu or 100% ram.

Attach a debugger!

e.g. `gdb`
http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/

`gdb` comes with `gcc` on Ubuntu etc...

Here's a how-to: http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbtoc.html

EDIT: just saw you already tried `gdb`. So, try running `strace` on it, it might give you a hint.

Further to that, try adding log messages to see how far the program gets (primitive, but it'll work eventually!)

Comment: An infinite loop could certainly happen, but is there a known reason the behavior would be so different from that of an infinite loop in a simple test program? Yes, I've tried running it under gdb, but same result, Linux hangs, ^C (which I would otherwise use to get back to the debugger) does nothing. Is there some other technique I should be using?

Comment: I guess it depends what's being done inside this infinite loop. Have you progressively added breakpoints in the debugger? You should at least be able to isolate the part of the code where it starts to go awry.

Comment: strace is great. You can also strace running programs using the PID. Try (for PID 1234) `strace -c -p 1234`, and then hit ctrl-C after a few seconds. It prints out a summary table - Happy Days

Answer (score 3):

> On Linux (Ubuntu 11.04 x64 in VirtualBox)

Probably you haven't reserved enough memory to your virtual machine.

Comment: 1 gigabyte. I'm quite prepared to believe that's not enough, but when I write a small test program that malloc's in an infinite loop, Linux kills it. Are there known circumstances under which a program running out of memory will cause Linux to hang?